# Procedure entry point K32EnumProcessModules could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++17, windows-server-2008

My C++ application fails to launch on a **Windows 2008 SP2** machine with the following error.

> ---
>
> ### My-Application.exe - Entry Point Not Found
>
> The procedure entry point K32EnumProcessModules could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll.

Interestingly it works fine on a Windows 2008 R2 environment. This program also works fine on other OS (such as Windows 10, Server 2012, 2016 and 2019). The Windows Server 2008 SP2 is up to date on this device and showing no patches that need to be installed. I have tried installing various flavors of Visual C++ runtime as well without any luck. My program has a dependency on many other libraries that are linked statically.

Any idea how can I know which part of my application is consuming this module that is causing the issue?

**UPDATE:**
I have already tried the solution in the question suggested for the duplicate. That didn't help me solve my issue.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the OP has tried the solution in the proposed duplicate and it didn't work. The possible duplicate does not address the issue the OP is facing specifically with Win 2008 SP2.

Comment: See [this TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c024b3f-1558-4da4-a014-9b4fecefd52b/sccm-cb-1710-client-issues?forum=ConfigMgrCBGeneral) and [this twitter thread](https://twitter.com/djammmer/status/940678556597633024) (_"Only known issue is client won't install on w2k8sp2.  Will doc soon, and eventually release a hotfix."_) which discuss your issue, specifically with respect to Win 2008 SP2. From that twitter thread: _"it's fix with KB4086143 hotfix rollup"_. Do you have KB4086143 applied?

Comment: Nops I don't see KB4086143 installed. However, this hotfix looks to be applicable to SCCM. I am not too familiar with SCCM and not sure if this component is applicable to the device in question. Is SCCM part of the OS or an additional component that has to be installed separately? As I mentioned in the question, the device is up to date and windows update is not showing KB4086143 or any other missing updates.